# Map content won't repeat when I scroll horizontally in React Leaflet Maps

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I've drawn a polyline of a satellite trajectory in **React Leaflet**. I want to either adapt the polyline when I **scroll horizontally** as it does in Google Maps or set bounds so that users can't scroll beyond one single instance of the view.
I've tried adding the repeat attribute to Polyline and other methods but I couldn't get it to work so I kindly want to ask your help!

Here's a video that shows how the polyline only shows in one single view of the map:
https://streamable.com/f99v66

Thanks in advance!

```
<MapContainer
   ref={mapRef}
   center={center}
   minZoom={1}
   zoom={4}
   style={mapContainerStyle}
 >
   <TileLayer
     attribution='&copy; <a href="Thanks for your help!'
     url={mapTheme}
   />

   <Polyline positions={geodesic.getLatLngs()} color="#EE4B2B" weight={3} />
 </MapContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the ability to repeat vector layers, but you can disable repeating of a map view by adding `noWrap: true` to the tilelayer options. If your line is not changing over time and you want to repeat it - you can create a custom tileset via QGIS or Mapbox studio and add this line to your map as tiles.